# loop and create numbering with condition base in array object key in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-5

Hi im trying to create this kind of loop pattern base on the array object key condition,
if the **'o'** has **'t'** we will start the index from the **'n'** starting point in object else we continue the numbering from main counter

**data array:**

```
 let data = [
  {o:[],n:1}, //empty o could be our main counter this could also be dynamic or any number to start
  {o:[],n:1},
  {o:['t'],n:1}, //has t number start from n
  {o:['t'],n:1}, 
  {o:[],n:1}, // continue the last count of main counter
  {o:[],n:1},
  {o:['t'],n:1},
  {o:[],n:1},
  {o:[],n:1},
  {o:['t'],n:5},
  {o:['t'],n:5},
  {o:['t'],n:5}, 
  {o:[],n:1}, 
]
```

**then when i run this code:**

```
 recount(data){
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     //code here 
     //new can also modify data[i].n
     console.log(**numbering**)
   }
 }
```

**expected result**

```
//numbering
//1,2,1,2,3,4,1,5,6,5,6,7,7
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: do you have to use es5? I see that you're using `let` which is an es6 feature

Comment: @NickParsons and shorthand method notation `recount(data)` which is also ES6.

Comment: yes but its optional, we can use  or dont use it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a straight forward loop but it needs to keep two counters:

- One is the normal counter which is for items where `o` doesn't contain `"t"` and we just increment it every time.
- The other  is an offset to add to `n` when `o` contains `"t"`. It starts at zero.

  - It increases by one for each successive item that matches the condition.
  - It resets back to zero if a we stop encountering items that match the condition.

Using only ES5, this can look like this:

```js
var data = [
  {o:[],n:1}, //empty o could be our main counter this could also be dynamic or any number to start
  {o:[],n:1},
  {o:['t'],n:1}, //has t number start from n
  {o:['t'],n:1}, 
  {o:[],n:1}, // continue the last count of main counter
  {o:[],n:1},
  {o:['t'],n:1},
  {o:[],n:1},
  {o:[],n:1},
  {o:['t'],n:5},
  {o:['t'],n:5},
  {o:['t'],n:5}, 
  {o:[],n:1}, 
]

function recount(data) {
  var counter = 1;
  var offsetT = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    if (item.o.indexOf("t") != -1) {
      item.n = item.n + offsetT++;
    } else {
      offsetT = 0;
      item.n = counter++;
    }
    console.log(item.n);
  }
}

recount(data);
console.log(data);
```

For completeness, a ES6 version of the code is almost the same:

```js
var data = [
  {o:[],n:1}, //empty o could be our main counter this could also be dynamic or any number to start
  {o:[],n:1},
  {o:['t'],n:1}, //has t number start from n
  {o:['t'],n:1}, 
  {o:[],n:1}, // continue the last count of main counter
  {o:[],n:1},
  {o:['t'],n:1},
  {o:[],n:1},
  {o:[],n:1},
  {o:['t'],n:5},
  {o:['t'],n:5},
  {o:['t'],n:5}, 
  {o:[],n:1}, 
]

function recount(data) {
  let counter = 1; //let instead of var
  let offsetT = 0; //let instead of var

  for (let item of data) { //for..of instead of a normal for
    if (item.o.includes("t")) { //includes instead of indexOf
      item.n = item.n + offsetT++;
    } else {
      offsetT = 0;
      item.n = counter++;
    }
    console.log(item.n);
  }
}

recount(data);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you @VLAZ :) it almost work. but the starting number is always 1. at index 0 of data.. this can be dyanmic for exmaple we start from 5 the expected result now should be //5,6,1,2,7,8,1,9,10,5,6,7,12

Comment: @JakeGarbo how do you determine which number you start from? And does it impact the items where `o` contains `"t"`?

Comment: My bad :) it works now with small adjusment Thank you @VLAZ

Answer (score 1):

is just a simple algorithm, if you need help to understand it let me know and i can expain to you whatever you don't understand

```js
let data = [
    { o: [], n: 1 }, //empty o could be our main counter this could also be dynamic or any number to start
    { o: [], n: 1 },
    { o: ["t"], n: 1 }, //has t number start from n
    { o: ["t"], n: 1 },
    { o: [], n: 1 }, // continue the last count of main counter
    { o: [], n: 1 },
    { o: ["t"], n: 1 },
    { o: [], n: 1 },
    { o: [], n: 1 },
    { o: ["t"], n: 5 },
    { o: ["t"], n: 5 },
    { o: ["t"], n: 5 },
    { o: [], n: 1 },
  ];
  
  let numbering = 1;
  let secNumbering;
  let previous = false;
  
  function recount(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].o.includes("t")) {
        if (previous) {
          secNumbering += 1;
          console.log(secNumbering);
          previous = true;
        } else {
          secNumbering = data[i].n;
          console.log(secNumbering);
          previous = true;
        }
      } else {
        console.log(numbering);
        numbering += 1;
        previous = false;
      }
    }
  }
  
  recount(data);
```